# How can I insert each object into key pair value

Tags: javascript

I have a object like
where I declear some properties and value.

```
var obj = {
    "country" : "USA",
    "CApital" : "WDC",
    "President" : "Trump"
}
```

Now I am adding in this way, I make one id and in that id I want to add my object property and values.

```
var myId =  obj.President;

this.newObj[myId] = {};

Object.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    this.newObj[myId][key] = value;
});
```

My output shoud be

```
obj :{
    Trump :{
        "country" : "USA",
        "CApital" : "WDC",
        "President" : "Trump"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as Object.each.

Simplest is use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge copy of original object to new object

```js
let obj = {
    "country" : "USA",
    "CApital" : "WDC",
    "President" : "Trump"
}

let newObj= {[obj.President] : Object.assign({}, obj)}

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

I understood you want to create a new object with a property value equals to source object identifier evaluation, and inside that property goes the initial object. Something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  country: 'usa',
  capital: 'dc',
  president: 'trump'
};

function myPropAndObjectValues(obj, prop) {
  return {
    [obj[prop]]: {...obj}
  };
}

console.log(myPropAndObjectValues(obj, 'president'));
```

Pd. `Object.each` doesn't exist.